# jQuery ticker - how to set URL for #ticker-title

Tags: javascript, jquery, ticker

I'm using JQuery ticker, and its working perfectly, i only need to set title for #ticker-title, is that possible??

```
    $.fn.ticker.defaults = {
    speed: 0.10,            
    ajaxFeed: false,
    feedUrl: '',
    feedType: 'xml',
    displayType: 'reveal',
    htmlFeed: true,
    debugMode: true,
    controls: true,
    titleText: 'Latest News ::',
    direction: 'ltr',   
    pauseOnItems: 3000,
    fadeInSpeed: 600,
    fadeOutSpeed: 300
};
```

Any thoughts? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ticker.js file itself is added a href tag to the titleText attrivute, check below :

```
        titleText: '<a href=xxxx.aspx' + '>' + 'News ::' + '</a>',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read out the Hash like this

```
hashtag = location.hash;
```

I don't know if you can overwrite the defaults, but you can create the Ticker on pageload with the hashtag as name.

Comment: I think i got it in an easier way, thanks for your answer though